# How to return an iterator over iterator's items' items?

Tags: rust

I have a function that as its input takes an iterator over `HashSet<char>`s and calculates the intersection. The common `char`s are returned as a newly created `HashSet<char>` which I'd like to change to a general iterator over `char`s.

So, I have the following code (working example on [rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ace31425cd41d44d82257bbb2baad97)):

```
fn intersect<I>(sets: I) -> HashSet<char>
where
    I: IntoIterator + Clone,
    I::Item: Borrow<HashSet<char>> + Clone,
{
    let first = match sets.clone().into_iter().next() {
        Some(val) => val.clone(),
        None => return HashSet::default(),
    };

    first
        .borrow()
        .iter()
        .filter(move |elem| {
            sets.clone()
                .into_iter()
                .all(|set| set.borrow().contains(elem))
        })
        .cloned()
        .collect()
}
```

And I can't find a way to make it more general. Basically, I'd like to call `.collect()` outside of the function. I've tried removing this bit and changing the return type to sth like: `impl Iterator<Item = char>` but that just leads to an error `` help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `HashSet<_, _>` `` .

Comment: What about `impl IntoIterator<Item = char>`?

Comment: But there's no type signature you can pick that'll allow you to call `collect` on a `HashSet` it just doesn't have that method. That's defined on `Iterator`s.

Comment: What is "more general"? What do you want to do with it that you can't with the current signature?

Comment: `return HashSet::default()` tries to return a `HashSet`, you'll have to switch that to an iterator as well.

Comment: @isaactfa - but then there are problems with `first` - cannot return value referencing local variable `first`
@cafce25 - right, but even after removing the `match` I'm still struggling to return an iterator.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman have a choice to collect to `Vec` or `HashSet` explicitly.

Comment: That's because `cloned` will clone the items of the iterator, but `iter` creates an iterator the borrows, you need that iterator to own the items.

Comment: Does it really matter to you? You can always transform the `HashSet` into a `Vec`. Anyway, you can have a generic parameter `Collection: FromIterator<char> + Default`, and `collect()` into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to add an output type parameter:

```
fn intersect<O, I>(sets: I) -> O
where
    I: IntoIterator + Clone,
    I::Item: Borrow<HashSet<char>> + Clone,
    O: FromIterator<char>,
{
    let first = match sets.clone().into_iter().next() {
        Some(val) => val.clone(),
        None => return O::from_iter([]),
    };

    first
        // ...
        .collect()
}
```

The call to `collect()` is still inside the function, but the caller gets to request which collection they need:

```
fn main() {
    let data = vec![
        HashSet::from(['a', 'b', 'c']),
        HashSet::from(['a', 'd', 'e']),
        HashSet::from(['a', 'd']),
    ];

    // this could be Vec<char>
    let common: HashSet<char> = intersect(&data);
    println!("{:?}", common);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=001959893629637cb101ea73197999e6)

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `intersect()` is rather inefficient. It copies the whole iterator of sets for each element of the first set. You can write the implementation much more efficiently by starting off with a copy of the first set, iterating over the remaining sets and only retaining the elements that are also contained in the other sets:

```
fn intersect<'a, I, T>(sets: I) -> HashSet<T>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a HashSet<T>>,
    T: 'a + Copy + Eq + Hash,
{
    let mut sets = sets.into_iter();
    let mut result: HashSet<T> = sets
        .next()
        .map(|s| s.iter().copied().collect())
        .unwrap_or(HashSet::new());
    for s in sets {
        result.retain(|x| s.contains(x));
    }
    result
}
```

This still returns a `HashSet`. However, you need to create that `HashSet` anyway if you want an efficient solution for your problem. You can convert it to whatever you want later, e.g. `Vec::from_iter(intersect(...))`. I don't see any advantage in changing the return type of the function.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I was aware that there is this unnecessary `clone()` called on the iterator in the loop but couldn't find a way to get rid of it. With your approach, it is now super clear.